# insert query always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Im am trying to inject values on upload file. I am new to C# .net and I googled a lot to find an answer but cant find any that gives me the help I need. I have no problem of getting values from database but when I am trying to insert it always returns false. I don't know what else to do.

I have used the breakpoint on every single line nr but I really need help with this one.

As I said fetching values from database is no problem so I am connected but inserting always returns false. Maybe this problem is a lot more clearer for you gurus :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

public partial class Extra : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public int count = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Hello choose a file to upload";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 2000000)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "File is to big";
                }
                else
                {
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                    Label1.Text = "File name: " + FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName + "<br />" +
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength + "kb<br />" +
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

                    try
                    {
                        //open connection
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source='localhost';Initial Catalog=webDB;Trusted_Connection=true;Integrated Security=SSPI");
                        //con.Database = "";Data Source=JOHANNES-TOSH;Initial Catalog=webDB;Integrated Security=True
                        con.Open();

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150);
                        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150);
                        cmd.Parameters["@type"].Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.Int, 11);
                        cmd.Parameters["@size"].Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [CORE.uploads] (name, type, size) VALUES (@name, @type, @size)";
                        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        con.Close();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException err) {
                        Response.Write("<br />");
                        Response.Write(err.Message.ToString());
                        Response.Write(err.LineNumber);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line returns false?

Comment: what is this bool val1 = "something..." ; Response.Write(val1); doing there? this is always false.

Comment: Many issues with your code: your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader, etc. are not in `using` blocks. Also, you're using `err.Message` instead of `err.ToString()`, and `err.Message` is already a string, so doesn't need `.ToString()`.

Comment: Did you check your database to see if the record was there?

Comment: I see two issues, although not sure if either is the problem. First, cmd.CommandType isn't set to Text. Also, the `@size` parameter is set to 11 bytes, which is incorrect. If it's an `int`, it should be 8. I'd leave the size out altogether for an integer parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to specify the size of the parameter type for that case. Try it this way.
If this doesn't work, check your table name and columns name to make sure it is the same. Also, check the rest of your code.
Hope this help.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [CORE].[uploads] (name, type, size) VALUES (@name, @type, @size)";
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Edit : Also, make sure your connection string is good. You can find it in the properties of your DB connection if you open the window with the DB connections (Forgot the name of that window)